# How to go prevent a song from uploading if the query fails and vice versa?

Tags: php

I have a music application where the user uploads and song and some song information is added to a MySQL database. Right now as it stands my script takes the song, renames it, and uploads it to the server. After its already done this it then takes the renamed song and some additional information passed from a form and queries it into a database. Is there any way to prevent either action from happening if either fails? Right now if the upload fails then the query will not be run but if the upload works and the query fails then is my only option to delete the song that was just uploaded every time this happens? This might not be possible and I didn't post any code because I'm looking for an idea not a fix. Thanks.

Comment: Not wanting code doesn't mean you don't need to share what you've already tried. Not code-wise, but approach-wise. We still want to know what you've already tried!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send an AJAX request to the server to run the query. If the query succeeds you can start the upload. If it fails, the upload wont start.

If it succeeds, you can retrieve the inserted id of the database entry and put it in a hidden field on the page. You then start the upload of the file and include the inserted id in your request. If the upload files for whatever reason, you simply remove that id from the database.

NOTE:
Be sure to run all sorts of security checks with that id.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely be doing that!